# Python dataframe repeat column data in each cell as a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to repeat the whole data in a column in each each cell of the column.
My code:

```
df3=pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'y':[10,20,30,20,10],
    'z':[5,4,3,2,1]
})

df3 = 
   x   y  z
0  1  10  5
1  2  20  4
2  3  30  3
3  4  20  2
4  5  10  1

df3['z'] = df['z'].agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

Present output:

```
KeyError: 'z'
```

Expected output:

```
df= 

   x   y                z
0  1  10  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
1  2  20  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
2  3  30  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
3  4  20  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
4  5  10  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with

```
df3['new_z']=[df3.z.tolist()]*len(df3)
```

More safe

```
df3['new_z']=[df3.z.tolist() for x  in df.index]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to `list(df.column.values)`

```
 df3.assign(z=[list(df3.z.values)]*len(df3))


 x   y                z
0  5  10  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
1  4  20  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
2  3  30  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
3  2  20  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
4  1  10  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```